# get an integer from a user and find the next larger integer that is multiple of 10

Tags: python

I am going to get a number from a user and find the nearest number that is larger and multiple to 10. Here is my code:

```
n = int(input(''))
n + (10 - n%10)
```

but when I run it I come across this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ValueError: invalid literal for `int()` with base 10: `n + (10 - n%10)`

What am I doing wrong?

My python version is 3.9.6

Comment: What are you typing in your console as an input? Your error seems to suggest that you are typing "n + (10 - n%10)" in your input prompt instead of a number

Comment: The code you have shown does not produce the error that you describe.

Comment: @Seon, I am trying to run this script at once and this way get an integer from a user and then convert it to an integer and then run the second formula and get the result.

Comment: If you're typing this into an interactive interpreter then after you tell it to `input`, the next thing you type is that input, not the next line of code.

Comment: @khelwood, can you please help me more? should I add something to my code?

Comment: can you please provide the full code?

Comment: Change it to `n = int(input('Enter a number, not Python code: '))`, then tell us what you get

Comment: ... You have an  `input` instruction in your code. When that is executed, your interpreter will ask for input. When it does, type valid input.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, the same error. I am using visual studio code by the way.

Comment: Sounds like you're literally pasting those two lines into the terminal rather than running any script. If you have `>>>`, type the first line, hit enter, type your number, then type the second

Comment: @Iwo, the full code as I described above just two line. my intention is to run the code get a number from user in terminal and then print the result which would be the nearest larger integer that is multiple to 10 :)

Comment: @Iwo Changing the number type doesn't change the fact that the given error says that the second line shown is the input that is being given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works like it is supposed.
The problem is that you didn't input an integer and instead inputted your second line:

> n + (10 - n%10)

P.S.: I would consider changing your code to the following, it uses only one line instead of two, but that's up to you:

```
n = int(input(''))//10*10+10
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are giving the mathematical expression as input, rather than a number. When you call input and wrap it with int(), python expects to take the input and convert it to a number which belongs to base 10. Obviously any non-numeric string doesn't belong to base 10.

So you should write the second line after the input one, and wrap it with a print() to display the result. If you are writing this in the interpreter, then you should immediately provide the number you want to test, and then give python the math expression to calculate